# Confining AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to a defined frame in Swift

Tags: swift, camera, frame

I am trying to create a camera app where the video feed from the camera is confined to a size I've defined in a storyboard layout where I use an UIImageView, called imageView, to figure out the layout.  I've used the pin tool to constrain imageView to be a certain distance from the sides of the view but I'm getting a strange behavior where imageView looks right but the camera preview layer, called previewLayer, is off.  I'm not sure why this is since I'm using the imageView frame to define the previewLayer frame, as follows:

```
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    let viewLayer : CALayer = imageView.layer
    previewLayer?.frame = imageView.frame
```

It seems like I can't post an image but, what I am getting is the imageView positioned as expected but the camera preview layer is much smaller although I am trying to get the two to be the same exact size.

I'm not sure what I should do to make the camera preview the same size as the imageView (which I can move around on the storyboard).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the autolayout due to the pin tool, which changed the bounds of imageView.  However, the bounds of previewLayer were defined by the previous bounds of imageView, before the constraints were applied.  To fix the problem, I made a call to layoutIfNeeded(), which forced the constraints to be applied and so previewLayer got the final bounds for imageView.